# Why does DSolve fail in this first order differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following first order differential equation:
$$ g'(R)=-2 \sqrt{R^2-g(R)}+2 R$$

By direct substitution it can be verified that an obvious solution is $$g(R)=R^2$$

```
ode=2R-2Sqrt[R^2-g[R]]-Derivative[1][g][R]
g[R_]:=R^2
ode==0
```

Giving True as expected.

However, using DSolve (Mathematica 11.2 for Windows 10):

```
Clear[g]
DSolve[ode==0, g[R], R]//FullSimplify//Expand
```

we find

```
{{g[R]->-1+E^(2 C[1])-2 R-2 Sqrt[-E^(2 C[1]) (1+R)^2]},
{g[R]->-1+E^(2 C[1])-2 R+2 Sqrt[-E^(2 C[1]) (1+R)^2]}}
```

As seen, Mathematica completely missed the correct solution!

**Edit 1:** For more details on the mathematics aspects of the solution (and the two branches of the solution), see my post at the [Mathematics stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536410/how-to-solve-this-non-linear-1st-order-differential-equation).

**Edit 2:** Adding initial conditions like $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=1$, as suggested in the comments, unfortunately doesn't help.

**Edit 3:** Just for future reference I add the way I found to solve the ode and recover the $R^2$ solution. To do that define a new function $y(R)$ that should be zero when $g(R)=R^2$, in the following manner

```
g[R_] := R^2 (1 - y[R]^2)
ode1 = ode // FullSimplify // PowerExpand // FullSimplify;
DSolve[ode1 == 0, y[R], R] // Expand
```

which gives

```
{{y[R] -> 0}, {y[R] -> 1 + C[1]/R}}
```

The solution $y[R] \rightarrow 0$ implies $g(R)=R^2$ as expected.

After massaging the ODE as shown above, I can get Mathematica to give the correct solution, however I still don't understand why it failed in the first place.

**So, my question is, why did DSolve fail in this simple example?**

Comment: If you integrating equation ,then where is integrating constant `C[1]` ?

Comment: Sure there will also be a integrating constant, but why didn't mathematica find the R^2 solution?

Comment: The fact that you're getting two solutions here makes me wonder whether Mathematica is increasing the degree of the ODE (i.e., internally rewriting it in terms of ${g'}^2$), which then causes spurious results.

Comment: Also, how long does MM 11 take to find results for this equation?  I'm running MM 12 on a Mac, and when I run your code it doesn't provide any results before I give up and abort the calculation (several minutes).

Comment: In the example above, DSolve is nearly instantaneous in my machine with MM 11.2 on Windows.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I've looked at numerical solutions given by `NDSolve` and I can't get it to give me the `R^2` solution.  Note that the `DSolve` doesn't really give two solutions: it gives two expressions, which can match different initial conditions.

Comment: Some details on the mathematical aspects on the solution can be found at my post at the Mathematics stack here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536410/how-to-solve-this-non-linear-1st-order-differential-equation

Comment: What happens under MM 11.2 if you add the initial condition `g[0] == 0` to your equations?  Does it just spit out `g[R] -> 0`?

Comment: Another initial condition to try would be `g[1] == 1`.

Comment: @mikado:  I think this is because the function $f(g,R) = -2 \sqrt{R^2 - g^2} + 2R$ is not [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) in $g$, which means (in particular) that we shouldn't expect there to be a unique solution for a given set of initial conditions (i.e., the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem) doesn't apply.)  Numerical algorithms such as `NDSolve` kind of implicitly assume that the solution is unique.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert For g[0]==0 it gives {{g[R] -> 2 (-1 - R + Sqrt[(1 + R)^2])}} while for g[1]==1 it gives {{g[R] -> -5 - 2 R + 4 Sqrt[(1 + R)^2]}}

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Judging from the square root in the ode, which is not (globally) Lipschitz continuous as per Wikipedia, I think this is the root cause why DSolve misses the other solution, so I guess this explains the "why". Thanks for pointing this out btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can no longer test V11.2, but in V13, `DSolve` has been improved. It still needs some help.  The option `IncludeSingularSolutions` yields more solutions, but we need to rationalize the `ode` to get all of them.  Of course, the solutions to the rationalized `ode` need to be checked on the original `ode`.

The constant of integration shows up in several places as `Exp[2 C[1]]`. One can apply [`constSimplify`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268867/4999) or just do the substitution `C[1] -> Log[C[1]]/2` directly to get a nicer looking result. We check the solutions and find conditions for which they are valid.

```
dsol = DSolve[ode, g[R], R, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True] /. 
   C[1] -> Log[C[1]]/2 // Simplify
(*
{{g[R] -> -1 - 2 R + C[1] - 2 Sqrt[-(1 + R)^2 C[1]]},
 {g[R] -> -1 - 2 R + C[1] + 2 Sqrt[-(1 + R)^2 C[1]]},
 {g[R] -> 0},
 {g[R] -> -1 - 2 R}}
*)

cond = ode /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction@dsol // Map[Reduce[#, Reals] &]
(*
{R > -1 && C[1] <= 0,
 (R < -1 && C[1] <= -1 - 2 R - R^2) ||
  (R > -1 && -1 - 2 R - R^2 <= C[1] <= 0), 
 R >= 0,
 R >= -1}
*)
```

Likewise, for the rationalization `oderat` of the original `ode`, we solve the differential equation and find conditions for which they are valid.

```
oderat = Eliminate[{ode /. Sqrt[R^2 - g[R]] -> dummy, dummy^2 == R^2 - g[R]}, 
  dummy]

(*  (4 R - g'[R]) g'[R] == 4 g[R]  *)

dsolrat = DSolve[oderat, g[R], R, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]

(*  {{g[R] -> R C[1] - C[1]^2/4}, {g[R] -> R^2}}  *)

condrat = 
 ode /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction@dsolrat // Map[Reduce[#, Reals] &]

(*  {R >= C[1]/2, True}  *)
```

We can then assemble the final solutions, using `ConditionExpression` to restrict each solution (optional). All seem to be valid for some values of `C[1]` and interval for `R`.

```
allsols = {g[R] -> #} & /@ MapThread[ConditionalExpression,
   {g[R] /. Join[dsol, dsolrat], Join[cond, condrat]}]
(*
{{g[R] -> ConditionalExpression[
     -1 - 2*R + C[1] - 2*Sqrt[(-(1 + R)^2)*C[1]], 
     R > -1 && C[1] <= 0]}, 
 {g[R] -> ConditionalExpression[
     -1 - 2*R + C[1] + 2*Sqrt[(-(1 + R)^2)*C[1]], 
     (R > -1 && 2*R + R^2 + C[1] >= -1 && C[1] <= 0) || 
      (R < -1 && 2*R + R^2 + C[1] <= -1)]}, 
 {g[R] -> ConditionalExpression[ 0, R >= 0]}, 
 {g[R] -> ConditionalExpression[ -1 - 2*R, R >= -1]}, 
 {g[R] -> ConditionalExpression[ R*C[1] - C[1]^2/4, 
     R >= C[1]/2]},
 {g[R] -> R^2}}
*)
```

Re-check solutions, assuming the conditions are satisfied for each one:

```
Map[
 With[{conditions = 
     Cases[#, ConditionalExpression[_, assum_] :> assum, Infinity]}, 
   Simplify[Reduce[Flatten@{ode /. #, conditions}], conditions]] &,
 DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction@allsols]

(*  {True, True, True, True, True, True}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on this, even after so long :-)

Answer (score 5):

Usually a solution to an ODE needs as many constants as their degree. In this case, the solution

$$
g(R) = R^2
$$

doesn't requires such a constant. Analyzing the phase plane for this ODE we can observe that the initial conditions for a real solution should obey

$$
R_0 \ge 0,\ \ g(R_0) \lt R_0^2
$$

and for $g(R)= R^2$ we have a particular solution. Follows a plot showing the stream plot (phase plane) for this ODE, in red the particular solution and in green two solutions: for $g(0) = 0$ and for $g(2+\epsilon^2) = 4$

[image]

```
gr1 = StreamPlot[{1, -2 (Sqrt[x^2 - y] - x)}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -1, 9}];
gr2 = ContourPlot[y == x^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -1, 9}, ContourStyle -> Red];
sol3 = NDSolve[{g'[r] == -2 Sqrt[-g[r] + r^2] + 2 r, g[0] == 0}, g, {r, 0, 10}][[1]];
gr3 = Plot[Evaluate[g[r] /. sol3], {r, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green];
sol4 = NDSolve[{g'[r] == -2 Sqrt[-g[r] + r^2] + 2 r, g[2.01] == 4}, g, {r, 0, 10}][[1]];
gr4 = Plot[Evaluate[g[r] /. sol4], {r, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green];
Show[gr1, gr4, gr3, gr2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but might help getting help...

I evaluated the integral using the package `NCAlgebra`, which considers `g` as a noncommutative variable. You can see (it you click on the image...) that it transforms the `DSolve` into a `Solve` with two integration constants.

```
<< NC`;
<< NCAlgebra`;
DSolve[2 R - 2 Sqrt[R^2 - g[R]] - Derivative[1][g][R] == 0, g[R], R]
```

[image]

Maybe some gurus can infer what is happening from there (probably MMA transforms the ODE).

Comment: Quite interesting indeed, but I'm not so sure how to proceed from there! thanks btw.