# Is this second solution to this ODE correct?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica V 12.2 on windows 10.
I was using Mathematica to check my solution for this ODE.
Mathematica gives 2 solutions.   Any idea where the second solution came from? and is it correct?

Here is my solution, and Mathematica's solution

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] == 2*Sqrt[1 + y[x]]*Cos[x];
sol = DSolve[{ode, {y[Pi] == 0}}, y, x]

 (* {{y->Function[{x},-2 Sin[x]+Sin[x]^2]},{y->Function[{x},2 Sin[x]+Sin[x]^2]}} *)
```

Only the second solution verifies. And that is what I obtained also. The question is, how did Mathematica obtain the first one above?

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify@(ode /. sol[[1]])]
  (* Cos[x] Sin[x] == Cos[x] *)

Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify@(ode /. sol[[2]])]
   (* True *)
```

My solution:
The ODE
$$
\frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}y}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} = 2 \sqrt{y +1}\, \cos \left(x \right)
$$
is separable. Hence
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y +1}}\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}&= \cos \left(x \right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\   
 \int \left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y +1}}\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}&= \int \cos \left(x \right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\
\sqrt{y +1} &= c_{1}+\sin \left(x \right)
\end{align*}
Initial conditions are now used to solve for $c_{1}$. Substituting $x=\pi$ and $y=0$ in
the above solution gives an equation to solve for the constant of integration.
\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{1} &= c_{1}
\end{align*}
But $\sqrt{1}=1$, taking the principal root.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
  c_1 &= 1
\end{align*}
Substituting $c_{1}$ found above in the general solution gives
$$
\sqrt{y \left(x \right)+1} = \sin \left(x \right)+1
$$
Solving for $y \left(x \right)$ gives
\begin{align*}
 y(x)+1 &= (1+\sin(x))^2 \\
 y(x)+1 &= (1+\sin^2(x)+2 \sin(x)) \\
 y(x) &= \sin^{2}x +2 \sin(x)
\end{align*}

From the above, I see that Mathematica must have obtained two solutions for $c_1$ as $\pm 1$ when taking $\sqrt 1$.

Only then will it obtain these two solutions. For when $c_1 = -1$, the first solution that it shows will come out. And when $c_1= 1$, the second solution will come out.

Is Mathematica's first solution correct? Should Mathematica have obtained only that $c_1 = 1$ and not $c_1 = \pm 1$?

Comment: No, but it is a solution to the rationalized ODE, `y'[x]^2 == (2*Sqrt[1 + y[x]]*Cos[x])^2`.  This seems to happen "a lot," enough that I'm not surprised.  I'm not sure why it doesn't check, other than in some cases the checking might take a long time.

Comment: `DSolve` follows your path up to the point where you apply the initial conditions.  `DSolve` first solves for `y[x]`, squaring both sides and creating a quadratic equation for `C[1]`.

Comment: I came across a similar issue some time ago, see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214195/why-does-dsolve-fail-in-this-first-order-differential-equation

Comment: Maple produces the only solution $y\! \left(x\right)=\sin\! \left(x\right)^{2}+2 \sin\! \left(x\right)$ in according with [that theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem) .

Comment: The bug still occurs in 12.3.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[y, x, ode, sol];

(* The given equation ode is a non-linear (quadratic) ODE, which yields two 
   solutions, as expected. Since both solutions satisfy the ODE they are both correct.
   Note that the ODE is equivalent to: y'[x]^2 == 4*(1 + y[x])*Cos[x]^2 *)

ode = y'[x] == 2*Sqrt[1 + y[x]]*Cos[x];
sol = DSolve[{ode, {y[Pi] == 0}}, y[x], x]

(* OUT: {{y[x] -> -2 Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2}, {y[x] -> 2 Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2}} *)

(* In order to obtain a single solution, we need to reduce the ODE to
a quasi-linear ODE, by defining an auxiliary boundary condition, say
at x=0, that will constrain the solution to the one that we seek *)

bcNew = ode /. x -> 0

(* OUT: y'[0] == 2 Sqrt[1 + y[0]] *)

solNew = DSolve[{ode, y[Pi] == 0 && bcNew}, y[x], x]

(* OUT: {{y[x] -> 2 Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2}} *)

(* QED *)
```

Comment: Your claim " Note that the ODE is equivalent to: y'[x]^2 == 4*(1 + y[x])*Cos[x]^2 *)
" does not correspond to reality.

Comment: +1 for your workaround.